# Should QAbstractItemModel::index(row, column, parent) check for invalid inputs?

Tags: qt

Subclassing QAbstractItemModel, I have implemented my own index() method as required. I currently check for valid inputs, but I'm wondering if that's correct. I'm wondering if it's ever valid to create an index for a non-existent piece of data? Perhaps while inserting a row or column?

Code:

```
QModelIndex LicenseDataModel::index(int row, int column, const QModelIndex & /*parent*/) const
{
    /// TODO: Is this necessary? Should we avoid creating invalid indexes? Or could this
    /// be a bug?
    if (validRowColumn(row, column))
        return createIndex(row, column);
    return QModelIndex();
}
```

Comment: The index could be invalid when you, for example, click on an area where there are no view items. In that case, as I correctly recall, the row and/or column values are negative, and you need to return the invalid index: `return QModelIndex();`

Comment: I guess I should just look at how Qt does it in QListWidget.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[ I have a better answer. :-) ]

Although I merely repeat what [Giuseppe D'Angelo from KDAB](https://www.kdab.com/new-in-qt-5-11-improvements-to-the-model-view-apis-part-1/) has to say about this...

You must distinguish between an **invalid** and an **ill-formed** `QModelIndex`:

About invalid indices (from [Navigation and model index creation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/model-view-programming.html#navigation-and-model-index-creation) in Qt's Model/View Programming guide):

> `QAbstractItemModel::parent()`: Provides a model index corresponding to the parent of any given child item. If the model index specified corresponds to a top-level item in the model, or if there is no valid parent item in the model, the function must return an invalid model index, created with the empty `QModelIndex()` constructor.

This explains the meaning of `index.isValid()`:
**A valid index refers to an existing item, the invalid index refers to the root of all items.**

[Giuseppe D'Angelo](https://www.kdab.com/new-in-qt-5-11-improvements-to-the-model-view-apis-part-1/) first notes that an *invalid* index (with `.isValid()` returning `false`) is still a valid input to functions like `rowCount()`, `hasChildren()` etc.

But a `QModelIndex` can also be **ill-formed**. It can have a non-existing row or column index, and it can even be from a different model. And `QModelIndex::isValid()` **does not check that**.

Giuseppe D'Angelo says:

> I personally maintain quite a strong point of view about this issue: passing such indices is a violation of the API contract. A model should never be assumed to be able to handle illegal indices. In other words, in my (not so humble) opinion, the QAbstractItemModel API has a narrow contract.

But since *All Programmers Make Mistakes (TM)*, it facilitates the debugging process to check indices for being well-formed. For this purpose, Giuseppe D'Angelo introduced [`QAbstractItemModel::checkIndex()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#checkIndex) into Qt 5.11.

If you're still using a lower Qt version, you can simply write that function yourself.

Answer (score 4):

[ If anyone has a better answer, I'll gladly accept it. ]

Looking at the source for [QListWidget](https://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qt/source/c90855d246bcbef0e93cc9469a92a09ec13b90ce%3asrc/gui/itemviews/qlistwidget.cpp#L210), it seems that checking the inputs is what Qt does itself:

```
QModelIndex QListModel::index(int row, int column, const QModelIndex &parent) const
{
    if (hasIndex(row, column, parent))
        return createIndex(row, column, items.at(row));
    return QModelIndex();
}
```

It also appears that I didn't know about [hasIndex()](https://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qt/source/c90855d246bcbef0e93cc9469a92a09ec13b90ce%3asrc/corelib/kernel/qabstractitemmodel.cpp#L1632) which will do what my `validRowColumn()` method does.

```
bool QAbstractItemModel::hasIndex(int row, int column, const QModelIndex &parent) const
{
    if (row < 0 || column < 0)
        return false;
    return row < rowCount(parent) && column < columnCount(parent);
}
```

For that matter, I'm not sure why the documentation uses `index.isValid()` everywhere when `hasIndex(index.row(), index.column(), index.parent())` would be more appropriate. Then, I'm sure a `hasIndex(QModelIndex &)` method would be added. `hasIndex()` does the same check as [`QModelIndex::isValid()`](https://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qt/source/c90855d246bcbef0e93cc9469a92a09ec13b90ce%3asrc/corelib/kernel/qabstractitemmodel.h#L77) and more:

```
inline bool isValid() const { return (r >= 0) && (c >= 0) && (m != 0); }
```

Comment: Actually, a default QModelIndex() object is invalid and represents the root node. Therefore, hasIndex(0, 0, QModelIndex()) return true if there is a child below the root.